# pandas with pd.ExcelFile returns an empty file

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I am trying to use `pandas.ExcelFile` for a file with more than 10000 rows.

However, the response is empty.

My code is :

```
import pandas as pd
import mhf

full = pd.ExcelFile('./Data/Source/SCMS Data 20151023.xlsx')   
# this xlsx is in my local folder 
print("Sheetnames: ",full.sheet_names)
parsed_data = mhf.parse_raw_data(full)
# this mhf is a module that I wrote.
for df in parsed_data:
    print(df.name," shape:",df.shape )

# View ref top rows
summary, purpose, ref, data = parsed_data
data.head(3)
```

When i debug the code i see that "full" dataframe is empty

The output is:

```
Sheetnames:  ['Summary ', 'Data Purpose and Notes', 'Data Dictionary', 'SCMS Delivery History Dataset']
summary  shape: (0, 0)
purpose  shape: (0, 0)
ref  shape: (0, 0)
data  shape: (0, 0)
```

I tried open using `openpyxl` but I am still having problems.

Comment: It's quite obvious that the problem does not lie with pandas but rather with your own module. Since we can't reproduce the problem (we don't have your code), it is impossible to help. Can you post what your function (`mhf.parse_raw_data`) does?